# アクションバーにメニューアイコン画像が出ない

Tags: android, java

[ここ](http://qiita.com/gabu/items/53857fcfa871b921af45#%E3%83%A1%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)に書いてあるとおりにアクションバーにアイコンを出現させたいのですが上手く表示されません。
現在はアイコンではなくメニューアイコン（縦に「・・・」）のみが表示されています。これを更新アイコン（別途用意した画像）に変更したいのですが上手く行きません。
ソースはリンク先のものをそのまま使用しているので今は割愛しますが、必要であればご提示いたします。
どうぞ、ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

がActivityに記述されていますか？

Comment: はい、Activityに記述してあります。

Answer (score 0):

リンク先の「res/menu/activity_main.xml」の内容は以下のとおりですが、

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_refresh"/>

</menu>
```

もしサポートライブラリのappcompat-v7を使っているのであれば、

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_refresh"/>

</menu>
```

としなければなりません。(「xmlns:app=...」の追加。「android:showAsAction」を「app:showAsAction」に変更)
その辺りは、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: その点ですが、別のサイトを参考にして、すでに対応済みです。

Comment: アクティビティは、android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivityを継承していますか?

Comment: あと、すでに「app:showAsAction」にしているとの事ですが、逆に「android:showAsAction」にするとどうなりますか?どちらも変わらない、というのであれば、私の考えている事は見当違い、という事になりますので。